# How to get LOOKUP_KEY of a Contact from ContactsContract.Contacts?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, contactscontract

I have to select a Contact from an android device Contacts list.

With the following code I retrieve an activity with the list of the contacts on the device:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**After picking a contact, how can I get the LOOKUP_KEY of the selected contact?**

Instead or retrieving `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r2-334B29432‌​D314D2D29/2`, I need to get `0r2-334B29432‌​D314D2D29`, that is the `LOOKUP_KEY`

So far I'm able just to retrieve full Uri

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
      switch (requestCode){
          case ADD_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE:
             Uri contactUri = data.getData();
             String contactUriString = contactUri.toString();
             break;
      }
   }
}
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a simple API helper method for this - [getLookupUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#getLookupUri(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri)):

```
Uri contactUri = data.getData();
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri lookupUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(cr, contactUri);
```

**Update**

To get the LOOKUP_KEY, do this:

```
String projection = String[] { Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
  String lookupKey = cursor.getString(0);
  Log.d(TAG, "key = " + lookupKey);
  cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much :)

Comment: I tried using your way but it seems that data.getData(); and ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(cr, contactUri) give the same URI, that is always something like content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r2-334B29432D314D2D29/2

Comment: that's your lookupUri. what are you trying to do with it?